# Два глупеньких вопроса про ЧПУ и MVC

Tags: php, чпу, mvc

**1)** Во большинстве mvc фреймворках делают одну точку входа в .htaccess примерно так:

```
DefaultLanguage ru
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value default_charset "utf-8"
php_value data.timezone "Europe/Moscow"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Так вот меня волнует давно: для чего исключаются директории ( **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d** ) без этой строчки работает всё отлично, да и по моему мнению становится "безопаснее". Или я что-то не понимаю и это потом "стрельнёт" в будущем?

**2)**  Далее роутится всё примерно таким образом:

```
index.php

<?php

$deep = 1; // глубина в подпапках, по умолчанию 1 если лежит в корне
$exe_module = "index";
$exe_action = "show";

$route_array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (!empty($route_array[$deep])) { $exe_module = $route_array[$deep]; } 
if (!empty($route_array[$deep+1])) { $exe_action = $route_array[$deep+1]; }

/* ну и тут run module:action */

?>
```

Как при таком роутинге правильно сделать "якорь"? Тоесть:

```
http://www.mysite.com/module/action/#anchor

    или

http://www.mysite.com/module/action#anchor
```

Answer (score 1):

```
http://www.mysite.com/module/action#anchor
```

Единственно правильный вариант для якоря на той же странице.

Если взять к примеру Kohana framework то если передать якорь `http://www.mysite.com/module/action/#anchor` то получится что `module = module; action = action; param = #anchor` тем более если роут изначально пилится по `/` что не всегда правильно.

Comment: В каких случаях может быть неверно распилен роут по '/' если не использовать GET? Ведь даже такая лабуда: `http://mysite/////////////index////action////////////fullscreen` даст верный роутинг тк сравнивается на !empty

Comment: например ссылка вида `http://site/posts/page_1` последнюю нужно будет распилить еще и по `_` + закрывающий слеш будет создавать еще 1 пустое концевое значение, которое будет содержать "" - ничего, и если в роутере не продумать этот момент - иногда будут возникать проблемы с пытливыми пользователями, которые по незнанке или специально заслешевали URI

Comment: Про page_1 спасибо за информацию.

Comment: мне в Кохане понравился роутинг, там вообще можно любые шаблоны сделать даже http://site.ru/controller::action::parameters::page_1  и он все поймет - если грамотно в конфиге роута написать строчку )